# error loading data when deploying django with apache2

Tags: django, apache2, mod-wsgi

I have a django app working fine with `runserver`, but when I deployed it with apache2 and mod_wsgi I got this weird error:

```
[wsgi:error] ... WARNING load Error occurred during loading data. Trying to use cache server https://fake-useragent.herokuapp.com/browsers/0.1.11
[wsgi:error] Traceback (most recent call last):
[wsgi:error] File "/home/stockenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fake_useragent/utils.py", line 154, in load
[wsgi:error] for item in get_browsers(verify_ssl=verify_ssl):
[wsgi:error]  File "/home/stockenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fake_useragent/utils.py", line 99, in get_browsers
[wsgi:error]     html = html.split('<table class="w3-table-all notranslate">')[1]
[wsgi:error] IndexError: list index out of range
```

I don't understand the error at all!